# RegEx to match numbers in whole words only

Tags: .net, regex

I would like to match positive and negative numbers (no decimal or thousand separators) inside a string using .NET, but I want to match whole words only.
So if a string looks like

```
redeem: -1234
paid: 234432
```

then I'd like to match -1234 and 234432

But if text is

```
LS022-1234-5678
FA123245
```

then I want no match returned. I tried

```
\b\-?\d+\b
```

but it will only match 1234 in the first scenario, not returning the "-" sign.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm sure this is far from perfect, but it works for your examples:

```
(?<=\W)-?(?<!\w-)\d+
```

If you want to allow underscores just before the number, then I'd use this modification:

```
(?i)(?<=[^a-z0-9])-?(?<![a-z0-9]-)\d+
```

Let me know of any issues and I'll try and help. If you'd like me to explain either of them, let me know that too.

***EDIT***

To only match if there is a space or tab just before the number / negative sign (as noted in the comment below), this could be used:

```
(?<=[ \t])-?\d+
```

*Note that it will match e.g. on the first number series of a telephone number, time or date value, and will not match if the number is at the beginning of the line (after a newline)* - make sure this is what you intend :D

Comment: You're most helpful, thank you. This is far better. However, I failed to properly define the task: I want a match only if the positive or negative number is preceded by space or TAB character (I do not want the space or tab included in the match).

Answer (score 1):

There is no word boundary between a space and `-`, thus you can't use `\b` there.

You could use:

```
(?<!\S)-?\d+\b
```

or

```
(?<![\w-])-?\d+\b
```

depending on your requirements (which aren't fully specified).
Both will work for your examples tho.

Comment: still seems to match the cases that he doesn't want matched... (?) it doesn't match the numbers as negative numbers, but it does match the digits, because the hyphen is 'not a word character'

Comment: Code Jockey: you are correct. I need to match the "-" as well. Also the provided RegEx matched a lot of "garbage" (meaning non-whole words) as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `\b-?\d+\b` pattern is wrong because `\b` before an optional `-?` pattern will require a word char to appear immediately to the left of the hyphen. In general, do not use word boundaries next to optional patterns (unless you know what you are doing of course).

**You might use `-?\b\d+\b` to match** `123` or `-123` like **numbers as whole words**. However, here, you are looking for something a bit different, because the `1234` and `5678` are whole words inside `LS022-1234-5678` since they are enclosed with non-word chars (namely, a hyphen).

In this case, you need to extend whole word matching `\b` with extra lookbehind check on the left:

```
-?\b(?<!\d-)\d+\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rffsZQ/3). *Details*:

- `-?`  - an optional hyphen
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!\d-)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a digit + `-` immediately to the left of the current location.
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\b` - a word boundary.

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/EvqipM):

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = "LS022-1234-5678, FA123245, redeem: -1234, paid: 234432";
        var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"-?\b(?<!\d-)\d+\b").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
        foreach (var s in matches)
            Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Output:

```cs
-1234
234432
```